# Select a specific column in LINQ web service with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'd like to return only one column called `Name` from Entity Framework from a simple table containing columns `ID`, `Name`, `Gender`, and `MarkUp`.

When I run the below code, I got the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to 'System.Collection.Generic.List'

Code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using SimpleWebApplication;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SimpleWebApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for SimpleWebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class SimpleWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {


        [WebMethod]
        public List<tblStudent> getAllLINQ()
        {
            List<string> studentList = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                using (TestingEntities database = new TestingEntities())
                {
                    var studentData = (from table in database.tblStudents select table).Select(u => new { u.Name });
                    studentList = studentData.ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return studentList;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: it error out at studentList = studentData.ToList()

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the block with the using statements from the top of your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is the name, then only select the name.

```
var query = from table in database.tblStudents select Name;
```

And your list should be a list of `string` since names are strings.

```
List<string> studentList = new List<string>();
```

And you can assign the result to your list like this:

```
studentList = query.ToList();
```

Comment: then how to write at studentList = studentData.toList() this line still error out.

Comment: Coding Yoshi. you're right. it works. What if I want to select two columns?

Comment: just put more columns in your select like this: `select Name, SomeOtherColumn, SomeOtherColumn2`. But please keep in mind that if you select more than 1 column, then when you try to put the result into a list, that list cannot be a list of strings but a list of a custom type and that custom type needs to have the same properties as the columns you have selected.